# How to delete a Dictionary row that is a Double by using an Int?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a `Dictionary` object that is formed using a `double` as its key. It looks like this:

```
Dictionary<double, ClassName> VariableName = new Dictionary<double, ClassName>();
```

I'm using `double` as the key type as I require the keys to look like this: 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2, etc.

Everything in my system works great except when I want to delete all the keys in a group e.g., all the 1 values would be 1.1, 1.2, etc.

I can delete rows if I know the full value of the key e.g., 1.1 but in my system I will only know the whole number.

I tried to do the following but get an error:

```
DictionaryVariable.Remove(j => Convert.ToInt16(j.Key) == rowToEdit).OrderByDescending(j => j.Key);
```

Is there anyway to remove all rows per `int` value by converting the key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var filter = dictionary.Where(x => x.Key - rowToEdit < 1).ToArray();
foreach (var pair in filter)
{
    dictionary.Remove(pair.Key);
}
```

Comment: Why would you call `ToArray()` on that? That will just cause the data to copied into an array for no reason, especially since the next line immediately is a ForEach which would cause the enumerable from above to evaluate itself anyway?

Comment: The filter has to be copied into another container because otherwise it is a reference to the dictionary entry and an InvalidOperationException is thrown ("Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.") because the collection is changed in the loop when items are removed. I know because I initially wrote the test case without ToArray(). :-)

Comment: Thanks very much for that. It worked a treat :) I've also changed to use Decimals as well as per @DrJokepu suggestion.

Comment: For anyone who comes across this later, just a warning that this wouldn't always work for negative numbers ([-2.3] - [1] = -3.3 < 1). This shouldn't affect the OP's choice for accepting the answer, but just as a note to watch out for.

Comment: For my case there will only ever be positive numbers created for the keys but thanks for the heads up. Not sure why you'd want a dictionary object with negative keys anyways but that's prob another question ;)

Comment: This code won't work for large integers as doubles lose precision for large ints.

Answer (score 6):

First, **consider using Decimal instead of Double**. Double is floating-point and it is not appropriate for exact comparisons (which is essential for key-value lookups). You would still be able to handle numbers such as 1.1 or 2.2.

Second, what you need is:

```
dictionary.Remove(rowToEdit); // where rowToEdit is the
                              // key of the key-value par you want
                              // to remove
```

**EDIT**: To remove values where rowToEdit is an integer and you want remove everthing where `rowToEdit <= k < (rowToEdit + 1)`

```
var removedKeys = x.Keys
    .Where(k => k >= 0 ? Math.Floor(k) : Math.Ceiling(k) == rowToEdit).ToArray();
foreach (var key in removedKeys) dictionary.Remove(key);
```

Comment: He's asking to remove dictionary entries with keys 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, etc. when rowToEdit is 1 (for example).

Comment: Jamie's answer works fine for doubles, so although I agree that Decimals are usually safer than Doubles, it's not really relevant to this question.

Comment: @ho: It's a preemptive general advice. If he uses floating-point arithmetic to find the keys of rows he will run into hard-to-debug bugs.

Comment: Can't you just use `RemoveAll` instead of a `foreach`?

Comment: @James: Dictonary<T> does not expose such a method unfortunately.

Comment: While I agree with DrJokepu's approach, couldn't you also just cast the double as an int? According to the documentation, casting double as int just truncates it. I don't know LINQ or if this would work, but I would hazard to try something like `Where(k => (int)k == rowToEdit)`.

Comment: @ccomet: That would work as well, however, it would have the same bug as I had in my previous example; it wouldn't work correctly for negative values of k. Hence my change to Math.Floor() and Math.Ceiling()

Comment: @DrJokepu, Ah I was assuming instead of using the `Where` you could directly replace this with `RemoveAll` (LINQ). However, you could wrap up your `foreach` into an Extension method of Dictionary. Would be a handy utility :)

Comment: @DrJokepu Hah, I didn't notice the Math.Floor() or Math.Ceiling() until now. Given the style of the dictionary I wouldn't expect negative values but sometimes it is better to have more universally operational code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ:

```
var itemsToDelete = from key in dictionary.Keys where ((int)key).Equals(intValueToDelete) select key;
foreach (var keyToDelete in itemsToDelete)
{
    dictionary.Remove(value);
}
```